# Resistance network

Tags: switches, resistance

I'm looking to create a circuit which will be used to test external PCBs. One of the external circuits features four switches with three resistors in what I believe is known as a resistance ladder (or network). The schematic for this is below:

[image]

Could someone very kindly draw me a basic circuit which features four LEDs which illuminate depending on which switch is being operated on the external circuit? Hopefully this isn't too complicated?

I.e if SW1 is being pressed on this external circuit then LED1 illuminates on our circuit and so on.

I'd really appreciate any help or advice with this! Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could use these pushbutton switches ([here](http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m0va55YNKv1qf00w4.png)) as a means to separate the leds electrically from the ladder.

Comment: What are your constraints? Can you use a microprocessor? This SE is not a design service, nor will most folks be motivated to do what looks like homework. What have you tried?

Comment: I have no constraints other than the external circuit cannot be alterered as that's what it is. So unfortunately I cannot use different switches. I haven't tried anything as I simply don't know where to start. I'm not looking to offend people and it certainly isn't homework, I'm simply asking for some basic guidance on how to go about this, do I need to use some form of analogue to digital converter?

Comment: @jdv  Unless our friend nb86 is strong with code, I doubt that a microprocessor is going to satisfy the "isn't too complicated" requirement.

Comment: @nb86, you are going to have to share more, as this is feeling like an "XY problem" if it isn't homework. What you are asking is to design the actual hard part of the circuit that connects to (1) and (2). But we don't know the voltages you are using, or the limits on what you connect to those points, or anything other than you have a bunch of switches that will behave like voltage dividers.

Comment: @nb86 start at the beginning: why are you doing this, and what are the limits of the hardware available to you (either because you don't have many parts, or you are constrained in some manner). This look *a lot* like coursework. It is fine to ask for help with coursework, but you will be expected to do your own thinking.

Comment: @NickAlexeev, given how common embedded devices are in early courses these days, and how easy they are to program (relatively) it really depends on where this question comes from. I mean, I'm a software guy, and to me the easiest thing to do is solve this with minimal hardware and not very complicated code. I admit I wouldn't be able to design a pure discrete hardware solution to this problem without a lot of help. (It occurs to me that there are probably ICs that could take a voltage level and easily decode that to 3 or 4 "data" lines that could drive a LED with the help of a transistor.)

Comment: I don't know what else I can add, that above circuit is as it is, I cannot alter it, they are already in existance in the product, I simply want to create an external circuit (a 'tester') which I can plug in to pins 1 and 2 which will enable me to electrically check the switches on this external design are working, ideally by a simple visual indentification like illuminating one of four LEDs which can be marked to correspond to the switches. Any voltage going in to the swtches on this external circuit is fine, 5v, 12v it doesn't really matter.

Comment: @nb86, well, you need to know your reference voltage so you can determine if you need to attenuate or amplify the voltages you get when the divider network comes into play. This will give you your bounds, and each switch will represent some value from 0V to your upper bound.  I'm lazy and might use a microcontroller, but there are dedicated "Analog to Digital Converter" chips from the usual suspects that I suspect would give you everything you need. Check those references for data sheets, because that can give you design ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Do some studies on LM3914 bar graph driver... This ic can be configured to lit any one of the 10 LEDs on its output line depending on the input voltage.

You only need to scale your resistors (in your ladder) properly to lit any of the desired LED in accordance to your individual push buttons.

With proper resistor choice you may design it so well where if more than one button pressed simultaneously, non of the LEDs will lit.

As its said in the comment, here we don't offer design service, but if you can pick up something from here, I'm sure there are many helping hands will guide you through the design.

Using LM3914 is easier for non-software geeks. Not everyone understand microcontrollers so well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a circuit that lights an LED if any of the switches is closed:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcdud5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With different values for R2, you can make one that detects if SW1, SW2, or SW3 is closed (but not SW4), one that detects if SW1 or SW2 is closed, and one that detects if SW1 is closed.

You can connect all these circuits to the junction between the DUT and R1 at the same time. So when Switch N is closed, 5-N LEDs light up. (If you re-name your switches in the opposite order, you can have N LEDs light up when switch N is closed)

If you want a different LED to light for each switch (instead of 5-N lights lit when switch N is closed), you need some digital logic  connecting the outputs of these circuits to the LEDs.

Of course if you did this with a microcontroller with an ADC input, you could not only detect which switch is pushed, but you could also detect some kinds of manufacturing faults like the wrong value resistor being loaded.